# accessing one app from another app

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Can someone explain me how to control one application from another application? I'm running a music player in an app1 using service class. And I want to stop that music player from another app.,i.e app2. But, I'm fallin short o the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you need to do.

Opening another activity (or sending messages) is by using Intents:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    // ...
    startActivity(intent);
```

Starting service is by using `startService()`

What you are trying to do can also be done using Intent broadcasts but only if your target app supports and listens to specific actions on the broadcast. You need to see if there is such an [ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to continue this question a bit.

In my case, I'm developing the target app and I need to implement few simple procedure calls for the main app. Basically 'start', 'stop' and 'sendData'. As I wrote, I'm developing the target app so I can support whatever I want. Which would you say is the easiest way to handle.

The whole situation a bit more explained. Main app would like my app to start it's work, and if needed they'll request that I turn myself off and when the main app is closing it would request me to send my data forward.

I'm quite new to android development, so code snippets are preferable. Thank you.